# How to add an asset to DAM?

Tags: aem, sling

```
//asset nullpointer exception
Asset asset = assetMgr.createAsset(assetDetails.getDamPath(), inputStream, "image/jpeg", true);

Resource metadataRes = asset.adaptTo(Resource.class).getChild("jcr:content/metadata");
ModifiableValueMap map = metadataRes.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
map.remove("dc:title");
map.put("dc:description", assetDetails.getAssetDescription());
map.put("sourceId", assetDetails.getSourceId());
map.put("dc:title", assetDetails.getAssetTitle());
resourceResolver.commit();
```

Getting `asset` as null.

Is any other way to get Resource?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are you trying to do? Can you give us more detail about `assetDetails`? Is `inputStream != null`? We need more information to help you. Right now it appears that you are trying to _create_ a _new_ asset at the exact same path where another asset (represented by `assetDetails`) already exists.

Comment: Check you error logs. There may be warning about asset size or location. This is also possible when assetStream is in wrong state or is 0 size.